# Alternative ways of finding and assigning values in LinkedHashMap inside ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, linkedhashmap

I have a code displayed below and its just working fine. But I was wondering if there are other ways to implement this? Basically what I am doing with 4 loops is to compare and assign a new value to Key of CopyMatrix which is a linkedhashmap inside an arraylist if a match is found using the String/Element in SeqGenerate. I had another solution which is also a loop but it wasn't working so am stuck with this one and am wondering if there are other ways to do this with a fewer loops or maybe some other techniques.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> SeqGenerate = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Double>> copyOfMatrix = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, DOuble>>();
ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Double>> calcLogProb = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, DOuble>>();


for (ArrayList<String> getArray: SeqGenerate){
            LinkedHashMap<String, Double> tempVal = new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
            for (String getString: getArray){
                for (LinkedHashMap<String, Double> entries: copyOfMatrix){

                    Iterator <String> iterKey = entries.keySet().iterator();
                    Iterator <Double> iterVal = entries.values().iterator();
                        while (iterKey.hasNext()){
                            String keyVal = iterKey.next();
                            Double Value = iterVal.next();

                            if (getString.equals(keyVal)){
                                Double temp = Value;
                                if (temp==0){
                                        temp=0.00000001;
                                    }

                                Double seqVal = Math.abs(Math.log10(temp));                         
                                tempVal.put(keyVal, seqVal);
                            }

                        }   
                }
            }
            calcLogProb.add(tempVal);
        }
```

### EDIT

ok what am trying do is like this:
SeqGenerate contains this elements

ArrayList -------- String 
(1)Hello World = { He el ll lo o_ _W Wo or rl ld}

(2)Hello Earth = { He el ll lo o_ _E Ea ar rt th}

Hello World and Hello Earth are an example of type of text contained in SeqGenerate but they are stored as two character sequence as I have illustrated. 
copyOfMatrix contains the same kind of sequence but i generated it from another set of sentences and texts but they're always a sequence of two characters that am going to compare and replace the value if a match is found.

So the only I know how to compare elements in nested loops is to make for loops so for example am going to compare seqGenerate element 0 element 1 to the keys stored in copy matrix. If i found a match am going to replace the value. Hope this is clear enough.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish here.  Perhaps a better explanation and/or some pseudocode?

Comment: hi edited my question for you. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't understand why you're doing

```
Iterator <String> iterKey = entries.keySet().iterator();
Iterator <Double> iterVal = entries.values().iterator();
while (iterKey.hasNext()){
  String keyVal = iterKey.next();
  Double Value = iterVal.next();

  if (getString.equals(keyVal)){
    Double temp = Value;
    if (temp==0){
      temp=0.00000001;
    }

    Double seqVal = Math.abs(Math.log10(temp));                         
    tempVal.put(keyVal, seqVal);
  }
}
```

The whole point of a `Map` is to avoid linear-time traversals.  This should just be

```
Double temp = entries.get(getString);
if (temp != null) {
  if (temp.doubleValue() == 0) {
    temp = 0.00000001;
  }
  tempVal.put(getString, Math.abs(Math.log10(temp));
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing your thoughts on this, I tried the code you gave me its working but it has the wrong output. But I learned something from what you gave me. The reason I have a while loop in their is because I wanted to loop through all the Key and Value pair inside entries (LinkedHashMap). Another reason is that I wasn't sure that third loop would be able to loop all through key-value pair of entries.

Comment: _Why_ did you want to loop through all the key/value entries, when you would find at most one entry?  There's no point to that loop when all it's doing is replicating the behavior of `get`.  Anyway, could you be more specific about the "wrong output" this code generates?  These lines should be _completely_ equivalent.

Comment: I was thinking that since copyOfMatrix is LinkedHashMap inside an ArrayList, I would also need to create another loop that will iterate through all the Keys and Values of entries which is inside copyOfMatrix. I thought that if I only create one loop for copyOfMatrix it would only compare the elements inside copyOfMatrix Arraylist which is collection of sequences with Keys and Values.

Comment: ...What?  You're iterating through each map in `copyOfEntries`, and doing the work on each map.  I'm really not seeing what the problem is...or what most of that comment was supposed to mean.  In any event, the code I provided should be _completely_ equivalent to your code that I quoted above.  It should do _exactly_ the same thing.

Comment: ok, if you look through the edited part of the question I have two examples there Hello World and Hello Earth. Lets say I use the same examples copyOfMatrix. First element of copyOfMatrix is this { He=0.0 el=0.0 ll=0.0 lo=0.0 o_=0.0 _W=0.0 Wo=0.0 or=0.0 rl=0.0 ld=0.0} second Element { He=0.0 el=0.0 ll=0.0 lo=0.0 o_=0.0 _E=0.0 Ea=0.0 ar=0.0 rt=0.0 th=0.0}. Before you posted your answer, I thought that in order to compare seqGenerate's elements with copyOfMatrix. I would need to create 2 loops as well for copyOfMatrix so that I can go through each sequence such as this { He=0.0 el=0.0 ll=0.0...

Comment: however I found out that its unnecessary since get() can get the sequences inside each linkedhashmap without creating another loops.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'm not going to re-write your code for you, but I will tell you that when I see heavily composed collections and nested loops, I throw up in my mouth a little bit.  Here's an idea for you:  All those collections can be extended, which means you can create custom classes that include find methods at each level.

My only other good recommendation is to try a language with lambdas, like Groovy, which has nicer capabilities for dealing with complex arrangements of data.

Okay, I had one more idea for you:  Would it be better trying to solve this problem using SQL?

Comment: Thanks for the reply no I have to do this using Java because I wanted to learn the language plus its a problem laid out for me. But am gonna look into customized collections as you have suggested.